# RegularExpression DataAnnotation Validation Attribute Failing

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want the following model property to be configured to accept a string with maximum length of 50, minimum length of 7 and only allow digits.

```
[Display(Name="My Number Property"),
 StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Too Long, try again."),
 RegularExpression(@"\d{7,50}?, ErrorMessage = "Digits Only Please.")]
public string MyModelProperty
{
    get
    {
        return this.myModelProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        this.myModelProperty = value;
    }
}
```

I must be doing this wrong because in all of the following values make the model invalid on this property.

"0"
"0123456789"
"01234567890123456789"
"01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"

Comment: [StringLength(50, MinimumLength=7, ...)] is available to specify the min length.  You can experiment with ErrorMessage as well using {0} and {1} to pull out the min and max into your error message.  e.g. "Length is max {0} and min {1}".  Not 100% sure on the formater though, but it's available elsewhere, so I assume it is here too.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `RegularExpression` by adding anchors like:

```
[Display(Name="My Number Property"),
 StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Too Long, try again."),
 RegularExpression(@"^\d{7,50}$", ErrorMessage = "Digits Only Please.")]
```

Btw, you have a syntax error too:

```
RegularExpression(@"\d{7,50}?, ErrorMessage = "Digits Only Please.")
                             ^-- it's missing a quote
```

You can check the syntax in the **[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

Comment: That syntax error was lost in my translation to StackExchange not in my code. Anyway I changed it to:  RegularExpression(@"^\d{7,50}$" this value does not pass but I expect it to because it is 7 digits "0123456".  This 8 digit value "01234567" passes as I expect it to.  So I changed the regex to @"^\d{6,50}$" thinking it was  zero based but yet to my surprise "0123456" still fails.

Comment: Try removing the length restrictions out of your regex to simplify.  ^\d*$  You can run some tests here: http://regexhero.net/tester/  rely on StringLength to enforce min & max lengths.